# Kahuna API - Is the secret key/API Key supposed to be kept private?

Tags: ios, security, mobile

I'm trying to setup Kahuna for my iOS app, and haven't been able to find a clear answer - the docs says that the secret key is meant to be used with the API Key for authenticating requests, but I can't find anything that states clearly if either of these should be kept secret/out of source code. Are these safe to put in my code, or should they be kept on the server side?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Are these safe to put in my code, or should they be kept on the server side?

Short Answer is no for keeping them on the mobile app code and yes to keep them on the server side.

**Why?**

Because they will be static secrets in your mobile app code, thus they are easily extracted by using any reverse engineer tool, like using the [Mobile Security Framewrok](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF)(MSF) to decompile the app binary.

**Alternatives?**

Well you can try code obfuscation, to generate the secrets dynamical in the mobile app or to store the secrets in the iOS keychain, but once more they can be reverse engineered at run-time, once more by using the MSF tool.

**Possible Solution?**

The best approach is to use a Mobile App Attestation service to protect the connection between the mobile app and the API server, that will guarantee at run-time that your App is not being man in the middle attacked, being tampered with, that is not running in a rooted or jail broken device and that is the same original one uploaded into the app store. This is done in the background without impacting the user experience by using an SDK integrated in your App and a service running in the cloud.

With this guarantees in place we don't need any-more to store secrets in the mobile app for Authentication, Authenticity and Integrity purposes, thus any access to third part services within the App can now be delegated to the API server that will be able to do a better job of protecting all the necessary secrets to access the third part services, like storing them in a vault.

You can find a Mobile App Attestation service in [Approov](https://approov.io/approov-in-detail.html)(I work here) that provides SDKs for several platforms, including iOS. The integration will also need a small check in the API server code to verify the JWT token. This check is necessary for the API server to be able to decide what requests to serve and what ones to deny.